# What is Slotted and pure aloha?

Tags: networking

So I am having a really hard time understanding slotted and pure aloha. I have understood CSMA/CD fairly well, but that is it.
I have the book: Computer networking - a top down approach, but I find the explanation very cryptic and hard to understand. Wikipedia did not help me.
Does anyone have a brief "aloha for dummies" explanation? or perhaps a video tutorial? I think I need something visual. I don't need to be able to create the protocol, I just need a general understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the explanation provided by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet#The_ALOHA_protocol) is easy to understand.

For pure ALOHA,

```
If you have data to send, send the data
If the message collides with another transmission, try resending "later"
```

For slotted ALOHA, the main difference:

```
A station can send only at the beginning of a timeslot, and thus collisions are reduced.
```